# How can I extract this block's material and apply it to a new cube w/ fewer vertices?

Tags: materials, vertices, obj

I downloaded an `.obj` file containing several low-poly blocks, and would like to use them individually. When I import this into Blendr, it looks like this:
[image: Imported .obj file; a series of blocks]

There's no obvious way of splitting these up, so I deleted all blocks but one, leaving me with: [image: Single block]

But look at those vertices! I think each color represents a small square of vertices? But, when I make a cube and try to apply the material to it, I get this:

[image]

Now, I'm really new to Blendr, so I just need to do some simple stuff. What I *think* is happening is that whoever created the original blocks mapped colors to vertices? So the material itself is just a smear of colors which are made orderly by mapping these colors to vertices?

How can I copy the material from one block to a cube w/ fewer vertices while maintaining the way it looks? *Can* I?

Here's the uploaded `.blend`:

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share the cubes (make sure that you've packed the images: File > External Data > Pack Resources) https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots sorry, i can't. the rights to these cubes are not mine to give up. :(

Comment: maybe show the Shader Editor, the UV Editor, the Image Editor, etc, in order to understand how the material was made?

Comment: @moonboots Hi. I decided to upload the .blend file—I added it to my post.

Comment: I've opened the file, your material is actually using an Image Texture, each face lays over a color of this image, if you ever decide to simplify the topology with a X > Limitde Dissolve for example, it will change the topology and therefore you'll lost the colors. The only way I see is to bake the Diffuse

Comment: You should look up some videos on how to bake high poly to low poly textures. The fact that it's a cube will make it alot easier for you to wrap your head around it.
I personally use Fluent Materializer as it lets you do one click baking for all your texture maps.

Comment: *"There's no obvious way of splitting these up"* - in Edit Mode: A to select all, then P key, then L key to "Separate by Loose Parts". As for the topology of those cubes - it looks like someone subdivided a cube so it has a lot of small square faces, each of them representing one "pixel". Then he colored them, and then he used some automatic process to optimize the meshes by merging squares of the same color and then triangulating them.